# Undefined index: id_digitado in C:\xampp\htdocs\SGOP_PPI\SGOP_PPI\multas.php on line 37

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de comparar la un valor obtenido por formulario, con lo que hay en la DB, pero me sale el erros "Undefined index: id_digitado in C:\xampp\htdocs\SGOP_PPI\SGOP_PPI\multas.php on line 37"

¿Que puedo hacer para que me compare y me traiga el resto de informacion de ese registro?,

Muchas gracias !

Hola, Estoy tratando de comparar la un valor obtenido por formulario, con lo que hay en la DB, pero me sale el erros "Undefined index: id_digitado in C:\xampp\htdocs\SGOP_PPI\SGOP_PPI\multas.php on line 37"

¿Que puedo hacer para que me compare y me traiga el resto de informacion de ese registro?,

Muchas gracias !

```html
<?php
 include("con_bd.php");

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM contrato";
   $ejecuta_sentencia = mysqli_query($conex,$sql);

 if(!$ejecuta_sentencia){
    echo'hay un error en la sentencia de sql: '.$sql;
   }else{
 //Paso 4 es traer los resultados como un array para imprirlos en pantalla
    $lista_contratos = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia);
    
   }
  

?>

<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Mostrar Datos</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
 </head>
 <body>

   <h1>escribe id del contrato</h1>
  <div class="form-group"  method="post">
           <label for="">id</label>
           <input type="number" name="id_digitado" placeholder="" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-grup">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="enviar"/>
      </div>

<?php
  $id = $_POST["id_digitado"];

 if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
  $consulta = "SELECT id_contrato fROM contrato";
  $result = mysqli_query($conex, $consult);
  while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($id = $consulta) {
     echo "encontrado";
    }else{
     echo "no encontrado";
    }
   
  }

 }
?>


  <h1>Mostrando Datos Desde Una Base De Datos</h1>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Pais</th>
    <?php
     for($i=0; $i<$lista_contratos; $i++){
      echo"<tr>";
       echo"<td>";
        echo$lista_contratos['id_contrato'];
       echo"</td>";
       
       echo"<td>";
        echo$lista_contratos['id_obra'];
       echo"</td>";

       echo"<td>";
        echo$lista_contratos['id_contratista'];
       echo"</td>";

      echo"</tr>";
      
      $lista_contratos = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia); 
     }
    ?>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu código tiene muchos errores y huecos de lógica. Mi pregunta es ¿Debo de teclear un código de contrato e irlo a buscar? ¿O debo traer todos los contratos y mostrarlos?

Comment: La idea es que teclees un codigo, se busuqe en la DB, y si lo encuentra se muestre toda la informacion del registro encontrado, sino, muestra un erros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que corregir varias cosas de tu código, algunas cosas no tienen sentido.

1. Cambia `<!DOCTYPE hmtl>` por `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. Creo que estas intentando que este mismo archivo sea el que busque y controle los contratos así que haremos primero la corrección del HTML. Para que un formulario sea útil, primero debes agregarlo al código `<form method="POST" action="este_archivo.php"></form>`
   Ten en consideración que en `action=""` debe ir el nombre de el mismo archivo donde estas trabjando y agrega el botón de enviar, debe ser un `button` no un `input` esto para que el DOM haga bien su trabajo. Este es el código

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Mostrar Datos</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
   </head>
   <body>

   <h1>escribe id del contrato</h1>
   <form method="post" target="este_archivo.php">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label>id</label>
           <input type="number" name="id_digitado" placeholder="" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Enviar</button>
       </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   ```
3. Ahora corregiremos la parte en caso que se haya enviado un dígito de contrato, no debes traer todos los contratos y luego hacer un `if` para ver si coincide, ese trabajo dejalo a la base de datos. Te añado el ejemplo

   ```
       // Validamos que tengamos un envío desde el formulario
       $id = $_POST['id_digitado'];
       if ( !empty( $id ) ) {

           //Incluimos la conexión 
           include("con_bd.php");

           // Creamos la consulta, si no le pones el WHERE siempre te va a traer todos
           $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE id_contato = " . $id;

           // Verificamos que la query no tenga errores, si los tiene muestra la consulta
           // Esto no se debe hacer en producción, pero ahorita te dará una idea de que estas haciendo
           if( !$result = mysqli_query( $conex, $consulta ) ) {
               echo 'La consulta no pudo ser ejecutada: <b>'. $consulta .'</b>';
           } else {

               // Ahora identifica si existe un contrato con ese ID
               if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) === 0 ) {
                   echo 'El contrato no fue encontrado';

               } else {
                   // Ya que tengo entendido lo que se busca es un ID de contrato y esto
                   // Por normalización de DB debería ser único exluiremos el while,
                   // Iremos directo al unico registro que regreso
                   $contrato = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

                   // Recuerda liberar memoria del servidor
                   mysqli_free_result( $result );

                   // Ahora si crea tu HTML para mostrar el contrato
                   $html = '
                   <table class="table table-hover">
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th>ID de contrato</th>
                               <th>ID de obra</th>
                               <th>ID de contratista</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           <tr>
                               <td>'. $contato['id_contrato'] .'</td>
                               <td>'. $contato['id_obra'] .'</td>
                               <td>'. $contato['id_contratista'] .'</td>
                           </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>';

                   echo $html;

               }
           }
       }
   ?>
   ```
4. Recuerda que todo esto es sugestivo, debes ser lo bastante hábil para acoplar este código a tus necesidades. Puede tener errores debido a que no se cual es la estructura de base de datos ni hay un documento de requerimientos, y de haberlo este no es el sitio, puesto que implica un desarrollo complejo. Confío en que podrás hacer los ajustes correspondientes.

El código completo luce así

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mostrar Datos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>escribe id del contrato</h1>
    <form method="post" action="este_archivo.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>id</label>
            <input type="number" name="id_digitado" placeholder="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-grup">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php 

        // Validamos que tengamos un envío desde el formulario
        $id = $_POST['id_digitado'];
        if ( !empty( $id ) ) {

            //Incluimos la conexión 
            include("con_bd.php");

            // Creamos la consulta, si no le pones el WHERE siempre te va a traer todos
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE id_contato = " . $id;

            // Verificamos que la query no tenga errores, si los tiene muestra la consulta
            // Esto no se debe hacer en producción, pero ahorita te dará una idea de que estas haciendo
            if( !$result = mysqli_query( $conex, $consulta ) ) {
                echo 'La consulta no pudo ser ejecutada: <b>'. $consulta .'</b>';
            } else {

                // Ahora identifica si existe un contrato con ese ID
                if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) === 0 ) {
                    echo 'El contrato no fue encontrado';

                } else {
                    // Ya que tengo entendido lo que se busca es un ID de contrato y esto
                    // Por normalización de DB debería ser único exluiremos el while,
                    // Iremos directo al unico registro que regreso
                    $contrato = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

                    // Recuerda liberar memoria del servidor
                    mysqli_free_result( $result );

                    // Ahora si crea tu HTML para mostrar el contrato
                    $html = '
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID de contrato</th>
                                <th>ID de obra</th>
                                <th>ID de contratista</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>'. $contato['id_contrato'] .'</td>
                                <td>'. $contato['id_obra'] .'</td>
                                <td>'. $contato['id_contratista'] .'</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>';

                    echo $html;

                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Espero te puedas guiar y te haya servido esto.

Comment: Alberto, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda y explicación.

Comment: Si te ha servido, recuerda marcar como correcta y votar arriba! ( Marca con la palomita ) Esto para que otras personas con tu problema puedan llegar más rápido a la solución